# Is there a query that can retrieve all the tables involved in a certain package?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g

I have a package that stores different procedures and functions in a PLEedit document and I was wondering if there is anyway to see all the tables that are involved in that package? Or maybe there's a way to at least see all the tables that affected by that package (UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE or example)? The package is quite big and will take a lot of time to go through it and figure out all the tables involved.

Comment: If it's Oracle, maybe you're after: `SELECT * FROM user_dependencies WHERE NAME = 'YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME';`? This will only reveal direct dependencies - it doesn't know about things that have been referenced in dynamic sql.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle:

```
select *
from all_dependencies
where name = 'your_package'
  and referenced_type = 'TABLE'
```

Notice that this will not extract dependencies given by dynamic SQL.